# Java - HtmlUnit - Cannot click on anchor with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I'm trying to run a search in our internal HP Project and Portfolio Management using HtmlUnit. But I faced an issue that I cannot click on "Search" which looks like:

```html
    <span id="SEARCH_BUTTON_LINK" class="primBtn" name="SEARCH_BUTTON_LINK">
        <a href="javascript:search()"></a>
    </span>
```

Here is my code:

```java
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()); 
    final String savedSearchURI = "my_url";
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(savedSearchURI);
    HtmlAnchor a = page.getAnchorByHref("javascript:search()");                
    page=a.click();
```

But nevertheless I still stay on the same page. If I do the same thing in browser - I moved to page with search results. Here goes what I've already tried:

```java
    BrowserVersion
    synchronized (page) {page.wait(2000);}
    waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
    waitForBackgroundJavaScriptBeforeStart(1000);
```

I'm totaly lost and cannot understand what's going on. I've tried to click on some other anchors with javascripts and some of them works perfectly fine (like login) and some has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Some times JS requires time to execute, so you have to wait for execution, best is to retrying for some time until page is not updated (using any condition) here is example of code

```
    HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
    HtmlTextArea textArea = form.getTextAreaByName("scandata");
    HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Submit");
    HtmlPage res = button.click();
    int input_length = page.getByXPath("//input").size();
    int tries = 5; 
    while (tries > 0 && input_length < 12) { //you can change number of tries and condition according to your need
        tries--;
        synchronized (page) {
        page.wait(2000); //wait
    }
    input_length = page.getByXPath("//input").size(); //input length is example of condtion
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I've already tried different ways to wait, waited for about a minute, while in browser this script works about 1-2 seconds. And it didn't help me. And I couldn't find out any other solution.
I thougth to try to switch to Selenium, but find another workaround and just another page with predefined search settings.